# Bootstrap radio buttons without plugins angular 2+

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to hide the round old school radio buttons from appearing on bootrap radio buttons? I am only using bootstrap css no jquery or other plugins.

Currently the buttons look like this

[image]

I want them to look like this

[image]

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active': radioYes}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" (click)="radioYes=true" > Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active': !radioYes}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"(click)="radioYes=false" > No
  </label>
</div>
```

Using Bootstrap 4. No additional css

Comment: Bootstrap hides the circles **by default**. If you have the circles show up, it's because another style is conflicting. Please update your question to include **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 and no additional css libs.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 with no additional CSS hides the radio buttons by default: https://jsfiddle.net/rqh8p169/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mo8oxxq4/ Using latest bootstrap

Comment: Just needed to add `btn-group-toggle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my mistake.

In the latest version of Bootstrap (4.0.0). The div containing the buttons needs the class `btn-group-toggle`

Relevant discussion -- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25281